# Defining Vim syntax regions for contiguous lines starting with the same characters (eg. comments)

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I am trying to extend Python syntax to define highlight regions as contiguous comment lines starting with `#'`. Everything after `#'` should be treated as contiguous markdown text and highlighted according to markdown rules.

My objective is to write [python files that can be compiled by pweave](http://mpastell.com/pweave/examples/index.html#published-from-script) in Vim.

An example would be where the paragraph starting with `# Foo` would be highlighted with Markdown rules while ignoring the characters `#'` in the beginning. For instance `# Foo` would be treated as a heading 1.

```
#' # Foo
#' The foo function below returns 1.

def foo():
   return 1
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
syn include @pythonMkd syntax/markdown.vim
syn region pythonDoxygen matchgroup=doxygenDelim start="^\(\s*#\{1,2}' \)" matchgroup=doxygenDelim end="^\s*\(#\{1,2}'\)\@!" contains=doxygenDelim,@pythonMkd,@Spell keepend fold
syn match doxygenDelim "^\s*#\{1,2}'" containedin=pythonDoxygen contained
```

Vim recognizes the block as Markdown but it fails to ignore the characters `#'` when analyzing the sentence such that everything except for the first line is treated as heading 1.

I have also tried the following. This treats regions as markdown line-by-line but still fails to ignore `#'` when applying markdown rules.

```
syn region pythonDoxygen matchgroup=doxygenDelim start="^\(\s*#\{1,2}' \)" matchgroup=doxygenDelim end="^\s*\(#\{1,2}'\)\@!" contains=doxygenDelim,@pythonMkd,@Spell keepend fold
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you got the `:syntax include` of the Markdown syntax working, but the Markdown region's highlighting is wrong because of the leading `#'` prefixes.

You say that your second attempt *treats regions as markdown line-by-line*, but that range (from first prefix to first line without such prefix) is still a large (multi-line) continuous region.

What works (somewhat), is defining a syntax from after the prefix to the end of that line:

```
unlet b:current_syntax
syn include @pythonMkd syntax/markdown.vim
" syn match pythonDoxygen "^\(\s*#\{1,2}' \)" nextgroup=@pythonMkd
" We cannot directly specify a syntax cluster for nextgroup, so define a group that contains the markdown cluster
syn match pythonDoxygenMkdLine ".*$" contained contains=@pythonMkd
syn match pythonDoxygen "^\(\s*#\{1,2}' \)" nextgroup=pythonDoxygenMkdLine
```

This will apply markdown highlighting after the prefix until the end of that line, individually. You'll lose the folding, though.

Even worse, because markdown has certain syntax elements (like `# heading`) that start at the beginning of the line, these now don't match any longer. The markdown syntax uses normal atoms like `^` to enforce those, but in your case `^` would have to mean *after the `pythonDoxygen` prefix*. **This cannot be achieved without collaboration from the markdown syntax**, unfortunately. (The plugin could offer a config variable `markdown_startline_pattern` that defaults to `^` and could be overwritten by your plugin to `^\s*#\{1,2}' \zs`.)

Most of the problems could be avoided if there were a block-like comment syntax (like C/C++'s `/* ... */`) that you could embed your markdown in. (Would `""" ... """` somehow work for you?)

Comment: Thanks! This is an approach I hadn't considered, I didn't know about `nextgroup`. In any case, the best would it be to have Vim reset the line after match such that it could interpret match on `^`. I am not sure if `"""..."""` would work in this case, but it would be definitely simpler.